# How do you check which intervals a cubic function will increase and in which intervals it will decrease?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I was trying to find the intervals in which the cubic function $4x^3 -6x^2 -72x + 30$ would be strictly increasing and strictly decreasing.

I managed to get the fact that at the values {-2,3} the differential of the function is zero. However this divides the function in three intervals, how can i know which intervals the function increases in and which intervals the function decreases in?

Note: I know you could simply plot the function. I was hoping for a more analytical method.

Comment: **HINT**: Differentiate it - that gives you the slope at any point along the function

Comment: @Mufasa I already differentiated it, that's how i got that the differential is zero at {-2,3}. What i don't know is which of the three intervals i get would the function be strictly increasing or strictly decreasing in.

Comment: The derivative is $12x^2-12x-72=12(x^2-x-6)=12(x-3)(x+2)$ Now use this to determine where the slope is negative, zero and positive. Negative slope implies function is decreasing, positive slope implies the function is increasing.

Comment: **Hint:** in order for the function to switch from increasing to decreasing, we have to pass a point with derivative zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a differentiable function is increasing or decreasing (or stationary) at a point is (essentially) determined by the sign of its derivative. For a cubic polynomial function $$p(x) = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d ,$$
the derivative is
$$p'(x) = 3 a x^2 + 2 b x + c .$$
Thus, the character of the roots of $p'$, that is, the critical points of $p$, is determined completely by the discriminant $\Delta := ((2 b)^2) - 4 (3a) (c) = 4 b^2 - 12 a c$ of $p'$:

- If $\Delta > 0$, then $p'$ has two distinct roots, $r_- < r_+$. If $a > 0$ (in particular, if it is monic), then since $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} p'(x) = +\infty$, we conclude that $p$ is increasing where $x < r_-$ and $x > r_+$, decreasing where $r_- < x < r_+$, and hence has a local maximum at $r_-$ and a local minimum at $r_+$.
- If $\Delta = 0$, then $p'$ has a double root, $r$. If $a > 0$, we conclude that $p$ is increasing where $x \neq r$ and that $p'(r) = 0$, so that $p$ has an inflection point at $r$, and has no minimum or maximum. (In fact, $p$ is strictly increasing everywhere, as $x < y$ implies $p(x) < p(y)$.)
- If $\Delta < 0$, then $p'$ has no roots. If $a > 0$, $p$ is increasing everywhere.

(All of these statements are reversed appropriately when $a < 0$.)

**Example** For our polynomial $p(x) = 4 x^3 - 6 x^2 - 72 x + 30,$ computing gives $\Delta = 3600 > 0$, and we are in the first case.

Comment: Can you just explain it in simple terms. Like compute the derivative and set it equal to 0, and then solve (or whatever one would do to solve this).

Comment: That's essentially what this answer does: Since we don't care about the roots, just whether they are real or not, we don't need to bother computing the roots---it's enough just to compute the discriminant, $\Delta$.

Comment: Invoking the discriminant is more confusing (at least for me) since I don't know what that is.

Comment: The discriminant is the quantity under the radical quadratic formula, so something you'd have to compute anyway to find the roots.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the leading coefficient, or you can compute the derivative at a point in one of your intervals (or all, depending on what you want to assume).

---

Let's look at this in a little more depth. We have the function

$$f(x)=4x^3-6x^2-72x+30$$

with derivative

$$f'(x)=12x^2-12x-72$$

We know the function is either going "up-down-up" or "down-up-down" (this you can say if you found two distict zeroes in the derivative- if not, then the cubic goes only "up" or only "down"), since you've found $f'(-2)=f'(3)=0$. We can look at the leading coefficient to check where the function goes up and down (if the leading coefficient is positive, then it is "up-down-up" and otherwise, it is "down-up-down". I might make this a little more intuitive if I say: in, for example, $x^3-x^2$, the $x^3$ will always win of $-x^2$, so in the end, the function will increase). We can also compute the derivative in a specific point in one of the intervals $(-\infty,-2)$, $(-2,3)$ or $(3,\infty)$, for example, in $(-2,3)$, to get

$$f'(0)=-72$$

to know that the function is decreasing on that interval, and so it must be "up-down-up".